# Get all entities ordered with Doctrine query builder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm getting a little crazy with this. I have a PhoneCodes entity and I simply want to retrieve all entities ordered by a field so no where condition but I tried to achieve this by many ways and not working. Currently I have this:

```
 $phonecodes = $this->getDoctrine()
->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:PhoneCodes')
->createQueryBuilder('p')
->orderBy('p.length', 'ASC')
->getQuery()
->getResult();
```

What's the way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: what is not working? what error do you get?

Comment: whats the scope? Repository, controller, service, ... ?

Comment: @Tomasz Madeyski it gives a 500 error. I'm executing this inside a Controller Action which I call through an Ajax call made with jQuery.

Comment: so if you get 500 error you also get some error message - what is it? (check logs)

Comment: ok...it was an error of type "Allowed memory size of x bytes exhausted..." looks like I was trying to get a data set too large so it was not an error related with the code itself. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should be something like this:

```
$phonecodes = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select("p")
        ->from("AcmeDemoBundle:PhoneCodes", "p")
        ->orderBy("p.length", "ASC")
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
```

Comment: as far as I know your code is exact equivalent of one in question so there's no difference

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a controller just do this:

```
$phonecodes = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:PhoneCodes')->findBy(
    array(),//conditions, none in this case
    array(//orderBy, multiple possible
        "length"=>"asc"
    )
);
```

This way you don't need to write a custom repository function.

If you wan't to create it as a repository function (e.g. in PhoneCodesRepository.php) do it that way:

```
/**
 * Returns all phoneCodes hydrated to objects ordered by length
 * @param string $order - ASC | DESC
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
function findAllOrderedByLength($order="ASC")
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("p");

    $qb->orderBy("p.length", $order);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes